# Values larger than 1/3 of a buffer page cannot be indexed Django error

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

I am using Heroku for the deployment for my Django application and I am trying to put a very long data into the table with the following model (adding the data to `content`:

**models.py:**

```
class ContentModel(models.Model):
    ref_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=120, unique=True)
    content = models.TextField()  #<-------
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.content

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("content", "ref_id")
```

But I get the following error:

```
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.OperationalError: index row size 3496 exceeds maximum 2712 for index "editor_contentmodel_content_2192f49c_uniq"
HINT:  Values larger than 1/3 of a buffer page cannot be indexed.
Consider a function index of an MD5 hash of the value, or use full text indexing.
```

I am not sure what indexing here means, if it is for searching I don't think I will be needing it, all I wanted to do is to retrieve the data from the table.

It is also asking me to us MD5 hash, so should I be using `hashlib` before I add the content to the database? The problem is that I am adding a JSON to the `content`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem you are facing is related to unique together index. Considering data you have is too big for index row size you should shrink down data by using function  that goes into index MD5 is good enough option as it still keeps somewhat uniqueness of data.

You should drop old index and create something like this

```
CREATE UNiQUE INDEX sowowindex ON mytable (md5(content), ref_id);
```

Comment: It is Postgre database specific stuff and Django is not supporting it directly as far as I know

Comment: I have already created the unique field can I alter the table?

Comment: I would rather drop it and recreate new one

Comment: I'm not using unique together but have the same error

Comment: @PavloKovalov does not necessary needs to be unique index to solve it same or similar. What kind of index on which kind of field you are creating ( post a question instead of asking in comments), solution could be same